# How do I make the div inline with td in table?

Tags: html, css

I've got a table and I've put a `div` inside it but now it's not in line with the `td`. I've put `display inline block` on both the td and div but the td only moved up a little bit. But it needs to be inline with the box. How can I fix this??
Here is my HTML code for the table :

```css
#box4 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-left:5%;margin-bottom: 10%;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Name:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>Here will be the name of the course.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Description:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>Here will be the description of the course.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Chapters:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Chapter 1</option>
        <option value="saab">Chapter 2</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Chapter 3</option>
        <option value="audi">Chapter 4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display: inline-block; position: relative;top:-20%">
      <h3>Video:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="display: inline-block;" id="box4"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Quiz:</h3>
    </td>
    <td><button>Do quiz</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Course trial:</h3>
    </td>
    <td><button>Start trial</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button>Community</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is what it looks like [image]

Comment: Why not show what you WANT it to look like. And why use a div at all. Style the cell - or why use a table at all use divs and flex

Answer (score 0):

your H3 elements naturally have padding and are pushing them down.

add

```
h3 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a little code added in the CSS file and define a class in the h3 tag

```css
#box4 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.td-video {
  margin-top: -5px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-left:5%;margin-bottom: 10%;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Name:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>Here will be the name of the course.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Description:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>Here will be the description of the course.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Chapters:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Chapter 1</option>
        <option value="saab">Chapter 2</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Chapter 3</option>
        <option value="audi">Chapter 4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
      <h3 class="td-video">Video:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="display: inline-block;" id="box4"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Quiz:</h3>
    </td>
    <td><button>Do quiz</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Course trial:</h3>
    </td>
    <td><button>Start trial</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button>Community</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in line css stlye from top: 19% to margin-top: -19px.

```css
#box4 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-left:5%;margin-bottom: 10%;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Name:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>Here will be the name of the course.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Description:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>Here will be the description of the course.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Chapters:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Chapter 1</option>
        <option value="saab">Chapter 2</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Chapter 3</option>
        <option value="audi">Chapter 4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display: inline-block; position: relative;margin-top:-20px">
      <h3>Video:</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="display: inline-block;" id="box4"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Quiz:</h3>
    </td>
    <td><button>Do quiz</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Course trial:</h3>
    </td>
    <td><button>Start trial</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button>Community</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```